# Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory Client does not support authentication

Tags: java, mysql, database, intellij-idea

I'm trying to connect with MySQL on the DataSource facilities.I have a database created, sql script, class where I get the connection, context.xml configuration file.

> java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Client
>   does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider
>   upgrading MySQL client)

```
CONNECT 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB?user=root&password=root';
    CREATE TABLE roles(

        id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE
    );
    INSERT INTO roles VALUES(0, 'admin');
    INSERT INTO roles VALUES(1, 'client');

    CREATE TABLE users(
        id INTEGER NOT NULL generated always AS identity PRIMARY KEY,
        login VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        password VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

            ON DELETE CASCADE
            ON UPDATE RESTRICT
    );

    INSERT INTO users VALUES(DEFAULT, 'admin', 'admin', 'Harry', 'Potter', 0);
    INSERT INTO users VALUES(DEFAULT, 'client', 'client', 'Peter', 'Parker', 1);
```

сontext.xml

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/testDB_MySQL"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
              username="root" password="root"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              defaultAutoCommit="false"
              defaultTransactionIsolation="READ_COMMITTED"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB"/>
</Context>
```

And DBManager class, where I get the connection and the data from the tables

```
private static DBManager instance;

    public static synchronized DBManager getInstance() throws DBException {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DBManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private DBManager() throws DBException {
        try {
            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
            // ST4DB - the name of data source
            ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/testDB_MySQL");
            LOG.trace("Data source ==> " + ds);
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            LOG.error(Messages.ERR_CANNOT_OBTAIN_DATA_SOURCE, ex);
            throw new DBException(Messages.ERR_CANNOT_OBTAIN_DATA_SOURCE, ex);
        }
    }

    private DataSource ds;
public Connection getConnection() throws DBException {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = ds.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            LOG.error(Messages.ERR_CANNOT_OBTAIN_CONNECTION, ex);
            throw new DBException(Messages.ERR_CANNOT_OBTAIN_CONNECTION, ex);
        }
        return con;
    }

public User findUserByLogin(String login) throws DBException {
        User user = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = getConnection();
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(SQL_FIND_USER_BY_LOGIN);
            pstmt.setString(1, login);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                user = extractUser(rs);
            }
            con.commit();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            rollback(con);
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new DBException(Messages.ERR_CANNOT_OBTAIN_USER_BY_LOGIN, ex);
        } finally {
            close(con, pstmt, rs);
        }
        return user;
    }
```

And DataSources and Driver[image]
What could be the problem? I will be grateful for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest JDBC driver for MySQL:

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: Yes, i have latest version. I just forgot to specify the correct version in the maven dependencies. Now I have an error Table 'testDB.users' does not exist, I probably did not specify a link to sql script(